# How to stop rounding in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that is rounding currency and I need the report to show the actual value. When I run the query in query designer all the values are shown correctly. If I output this to Excel and `SUM` the values I get the total I expect (e.g £56724.30)

When I run the report I get the value £56840.00 so it looks as if the data being used is getting rounded before output.

I have a Calculated field in the report called `Total_Rent_Due_UC_Claims`:

```
=iif(Fields!UC_Rent.Value = Fields!LastCharge.Value, Fields!UC_Rent.Value, 0) or 
iif(Fields!UC_Rent_Date.Value = Fields!LastCharge.Value and 
Fields!extra10a_d003.Value < Parameters!AsAtDate.Value, 0, Fields!UC_Rent_Date.Value)
```

I then use this to get a total:

```
=Sum(Fields!Total_Rent_Due_UC_Claims.Value)
```

I have formatted this field to currency to two decimal places.

Can someone assist with this so that the value in the report is the same as the expected value?

Comment: Not programming related?

Comment: could you try removing formatting to 2 decimals and check what results do you get

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "not programming related?" - SimonC

Comment: I have removed the formatting to two decimal places and result is still £56840.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this difference can be attributed to rounding -- at least not any rounding I've ever seen before.  That's a difference of £115.70.  I think the calculated field isn't quite doing what you want it to and needs a little modification.  I'm not exactly sure what it's doing right now, but basically both of those `IIF` statements will evaluate because `OR` doesn't really work the way you have it.  I would try the following expression.

```
=IIF(Fields!UC_Rent.Value = Fields!LastCharge.Value, 
     Fields!UC_Rent.Value, IIF(Fields!UC_Rent_Date.Value = Fields!LastCharge.Value 
         AND Fields!extra10a_d003.Value < Parameters!AsAtDate.Value, 0, Fields!UC_Rent_Date.Value))
```

Of course, this could still be wrong as I can't tell if all of the fields are date datatypes or if there's some kind of mismatch going on here.  Let me know if this doesn't work and I'll see if I can adjust it.

Comment: Hi SteveYour formula worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your assistance

Comment: @JohnK Glad to help.  Make sure to mark my answer as correct with the checkmark so others can find the right answer to similar questions.

Comment: Done, Thanks again :)